# Disable the accordion style of the tools menu in Adobe Acrobat XI Pro

Tags: windows-7, adobe-acrobat

Is there anyway to disable the [accordion style](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) of the tools menu in Adobe Acrobat XI Pro? E.g. in the following screenshot, if I click on "Pages", I don't want the "Content Editing" content panel to collapse.

[image]

I use Adobe Acrobat XI Pro on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

above "Content Editing"  there is an icon at the top right. Click it and select "Allow Multiple Panels Open"
The setting is saved individually for the "Tools" and the "Comment" panes so you have to enable it in both of them.

[image: icon location]